# How to handle long messages in Telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

I'm trying to send a super long text as a message after clicking the Telegraf Markup callback button.
But I got `Error: 400: Bad Request: message is too long`

I am new to Telegraf. Is there any way how to handle it? I will be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a function to split up messages in Telegraf.
It exists though and it is called Text Paging.

Another library used this: https://github.com/GochoMugo/tgfancy#text-paging
It's not updated unfortunately though.

The maximum limit of a message is 4096 characters.
So what you could do is something like this:

```
  const max_size = 4096
  var messageString = "Your Text HERE" 

  var amount_sliced = messageString.length / max_size
  var start = 0
  var end = max_size
  var message
  var messagesArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < amount_sliced; i++) {
    message = messageString.slice(start, end) 
    messages.push(message)
    start = start + max_size
    end = end + max_size
  }
  console.log(messagesArray)
```

Comment: Hi :) The script works just fine. I'll check for Text Paging. Thanks!

Comment: @AituuFS It's a good practice to accept the answer as the answer if it has solved your problem